# jquery on click event not firing when using jquery 1.11.3.min.js .

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per below html controls , if I try to change the "id" of Submit to "Save" , click of Save is not working then.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Submit Request" id="Submit"class="buttonclass"/>               
<input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" class="buttonclass" />
</body>
</html
```

JS CODE BELOW :

```
   $("#Submit").on({
    click: function () {             

        $(this).attr('id', 'Save');           
        return false;
    }
   });

   $("#Save").on({
    click: function () {            
       alert("Save Event Fired"); 
    }
   });
```

Comment: `id="Submit"class="buttonclass"` Add space before `class`.

Comment: Have space between , it got trimmed while copy pasting code here .

Comment: Any one there to help ?

Comment: You have marked an answer below. Did that not solve your problem?

Comment: Not fully . 
 
But why this was working with earlier jquery version ? 
What if there is one more button named "Cancel" and if I need to change the id of "Cancel" to "Clear" in "Submit" button click event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't binding the click event to #Save because the id #Save only exists AFTER the Submit button has been pressed (there is no #Save on load). But if you put the click event on the body and only accept the #Save, you can bubble the event up and handle it there.

```
$("#Submit").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()

    alert("Submitted Fired"); 
    $(e.target).attr('id', 'Save');           
    $(this).unbind('click');
})

$("body").on('click', '#Save', function (e) {
    alert("Save Event Fired"); 
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lchafwa/1/
If this is the answer you are looking for, press the green tick on the left.

Comment: But why this was working with earlier jquery version ?
What if there is one more button named "Cancel" and if I need to change the id of "Cancel"  to "Clear" in  "Submit" button click event ?

Comment: I edited the js fiddle to work with jQuery 1.11.3. What you changed your comment to wasn't your original question.

Comment: Sorry . I just asked because the same code worked in 1.8 jquery version well and now if i upgraded to 1.11 then it is not working and i had add more code